# Dynamic MobilePush Content using ContactKey in Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobilepush, geolocation

Need to get the contact key of a person who entered a location (using location based push message) and retrieve firstname from a different data extension. Since there is no Data extension used here, (unlike one -off sms/push/Journey entry Data extension) wondering which variable can be used to get the ContactKey.

Unlike _subscriberkey  used in Email Ampscripts, cannot use the same for Mobile Push and it doesnt work either when tested. Found the below documentation mentioning to use ContactKey.

However doesnt work . The script is as simple as below. Any quick leads would be appreciated ?

```ampscript
%%[ var @Name

set @Name= Lookup("CUSTOMER_INFO","FIRST_NAME","CUSTOMERID", ContactKey)

Hi %%Name%%, This is a test Message

]%%
```

Ref : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/personalizationStringsAMPscript.html